# Question on abstract algebra about Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I need an explanation,
why

> $ (\mathbb{Z}_7,\oplus _6 )$ is not a Group?
>
> As I have discovered so far. The following conditions are satisfied
>
> I) Closed!
>
> II) Associative!
>
> III) There exists identity element!!
>
> IV) There exists inverse!!

Where is my mistake?

On the other hand I realized that there are some awkward results like the identity element in that group isn't unique.

Comment: What is $\oplus_6$?

Comment: Yeah what is this operation?

Comment: Is $\oplus_6$ addition modulo $6$? If so how do you define $3 + 3$? Is it $6$ or $0$? If so, the idea is that addition is not well defined. But be aware, this is not standard notation (I'm just guessing from context!)

Comment: @Mathmo123  yes, I meant by addition modulo 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no identity element. If you think that $0$ is it, compute $0\oplus_6 6$.